# When I run PyCharm by clicking the Debug I cannot see the debug console with View > Tool Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Here's an example of all that I see:

[image]

I have many breakpoints set but the code does not seem to stop at them.

Here's an example:

```
import aqt
print ("ABC")
aqt.run()
print ("DEF")
```

I have a breakpoint on ABC line and on DEF.  The app runs and prints ABC but does not stop on the breakpoint.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What you are showing in the image is the python console and has nothing to do with debug mode or breakpoints. Press Alt+5 to open the debug tab

Answer (score 0):

If the process finishes with an exit code of 0 it probably did not ever hit your breakpoint. You can quickly test this by putting a breakpoint at the first part of the program. Additionally F9 should run the program until it reaches the next breakpoint.

> exit 0 means the successful execution of the program and a non zero exit code indicates an error.